# LostFocus Event of Textfield in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I am creating an application in which i want to add record in the database after focus lost event of the text field.
Which is the lost focus event of textfield in xcode??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you need is `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField.`

Check out the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) reference for more info >

Answer (score 2):

you can use `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField` delegate method of `UITextField`

Also you should consider using event `textFieldDidEndEditing:`

Hope this helps.